# Android: onAnimationStart skipped first time

Tags: android, animation

The first time the icon is clicked, the onAnimationStart() does not play, but the onAnimationEnd() does. In subsequent clicks, both play. Anyone know why?

```
private void animateOnAwesome(final ImageButton awesomeIcon) {
    Animation animateOnAwesome = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
            R.anim.hold);
    awesomeIcon.startAnimation(animateOnAwesome);
    animateOnAwesome.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            switch (ParseApplication.currentPosition) {
                case 0:
                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.raw.awesomeddd_light).asGif().into(awesomeIcon);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.raw.awesomeddd_dark).asGif().into
                            (awesomeIcon);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d("NO_THEME", "No theme selected.");
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
            awesomeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.awesomeddd);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the animation before setting the listeners. This should do the trick:

```
animateOnAwesome.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        switch (ParseApplication.currentPosition) {
            case 0:
                Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.raw.awesomeddd_light).asGif().into(awesomeIcon);
                break;
            case 1:
                Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.raw.awesomeddd_dark).asGif().into
                        (awesomeIcon);
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("NO_THEME", "No theme selected.");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
        awesomeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.awesomeddd);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});

awesomeIcon.startAnimation(animateOnAwesome);
```

Comment: Good catch, but that didn't fix the issue.

It still skips onAnimationStart() the first go around.